# react on the resizing of a QMainWindow for adjust widget's size

Tags: qt, resize, signals-slots, autosize, qmainwindow

How do I react on the resize of a `QMainWindow`? I have `QTextBrowsers` in a `QScrollArea` and I adjust them to the size of the content on creating them (the only thing that should scroll is the `QScrollArea`).

Everything works for now, but if I resize the `mainWindow`, the height of the `QTextBrowsers` isn't changed, because the reflow function isn't triggered.

Do you have any better idea to adjust a `QTextBrowser` to it's content? My current code is:

```
void RenderFrame::adjustTextBrowser(QTextBrowser* e) const {
    e->document()->setTextWidth(e->parentWidget()->width());
    e->setMinimumHeight(e->document()->size().toSize().height());
    e->setMaximumHeight(e->minimumHeight());
}
```

The `parentWidget()` is necessary because running `width()` on the widget itself returns always 100, regardless of the real size.

Comment: The standard way to have your widgets resize is to put them in an appropriately configured layout.

Comment: But there's no way to make `QtextBrowser` automatically resize to the smallest possible size that doesn't need a scrollbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is only text or html, you could use `QLabel` instead, because it already adapts its size to the available space. You'll have to use:

```
label->setWordWrap(true);        
label->setTextInteractionFlags(Qt::TextBrowserInteraction);
```

to have almost the same behavior as a `QTextBrowser`.

---

If you really want to use a `QTextBrowser`, you can try something like this (adapted from `QLabel` source code):

```
class TextBrowser : public QTextBrowser {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit TextBrowser(QWidget *parent) : QTextBrowser(parent) {
        // updateGeometry should be called whenever the size changes
        // and the size changes when the document changes        
        connect(this, SIGNAL(textChanged()), SLOT(onTextChanged()));

        QSizePolicy policy = sizePolicy();
        // Obvious enough ? 
        policy.setHeightForWidth(true);
        setSizePolicy(policy);
    }

    int heightForWidth(int width) const {
        int left, top, right, bottom;
        getContentsMargins(&left, &top, &right, &bottom);
        QSize margins(left + right, top + bottom);

        // As working on the real document seems to cause infinite recursion,
        // we create a clone to calculate the width
        QScopedPointer<QTextDocument> tempDoc(document()->clone());
        tempDoc->setTextWidth(width - margins.width());

        return qMax(tempDoc->size().toSize().height() + margins.height(),
                    minimumHeight());
    }
private slots:
    void onTextChanged() {
        updateGeometry();
    }
};
```